# Why isn't the one definition rule abandoned for C++17?

Tags: c++, c++17, one-definition-rule

Citing C++ Draft N4713:

> Every program shall contain exactly one definition of every non-inline
>   function or variable that is odr-used in that program outside of a
>   discarded statement (9.4.1); no diagnostic required. The definition
>   can appear explicitly in the program, it can be found in the standard
>   or a user-defined library, or (when appropriate) it is implicitly
>   defined (see 15.1, 15.4 and 15.8). An inline function or variable
>   shall be defined in every translation unit in which it is odr-used
>   outside of a discarded statement.

In C++ versions prior to C++17, I can get around this restriction by just declaring my functions `inline`. C++17 adds the same feature for variables.

Furthermore, it seems to me that the `inline`-Keyword does not serve another purpose apart from making it possible to ignore the ODR.

So, why isn't this whole rule just abandoned for C++17 ? I can't see the purpose of a rule that can be turned off.

Comment: Because if it's abandoned, then what happens when you have a conflict in symbols with several definitions of the same stuff with different implementation across translation units?

Comment: @Ricardo Why should it be abandoned?

Comment: Why would you want to "get round" a restriction that protects you?

Comment: Even with future module, we can break ODR :-/

Comment: Even with `inline`, the sources for the multiple definitions must be identical, so in that sense there can still only be one definition; it’s just duplicated in several translation units.

Comment: @Jarod42 but with modules - violation of ODR should (thats my guess) be recognized at compilation time, according to http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2018/p1103r2.pdf: `A variable, function, class type,
enumeration type, or template shall not be defined where a prior definition is reachable (100.6)`. So maybe ODR violations will be finally compiler errors.

Comment: @marcinj: Some ODR violations would probably be easily detected with modules, but we can still break ODR in so many ways.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

"Turning off" the ODR with `inline` is not free: the definition of an `inline` entity must be present in every translation unit. Note that this implies that any change to its definition causes re-compilation of every compilation unit that uses it. This would be particularly unpleasant when the function is part of some library many / big projects depend upon.

Non-`inline` functions, on the other hand, live in just one compilation unit and are referenced via some symbol by the linker when needed elsewhere. Complying with the ODR guarantees that symbol is not ambiguous.

Comment: ... and that definition must be exactly the same in all translation units.

Comment: @rustyx True. Of course, `inline` does not really turn off the ODR, that's why I out that in quotes. Those exact details of the `inline` semantics are not really relevant in the scope of this relatively high-level Q/A though IMO, so I would prefer to skip over them for the sake of brevity and clarity.

Comment: The ODR doesn't **guarantee** that a symbol is not ambiguous; it **requires** that it is not ambiguous. The burden is on the programmer. ODR violations do not have to be diagnosed, and they result in undefined behavior. One practical result is that when you have two different definitions of the "same" function you don't know which one will get linked in.

Comment: @PeteBecker That would probably be a language problem on my part. Tried to fix it.

Comment: @BaummitAugen -- yes, that's better. I'll leave my comment as an elaboration.

Comment: @PeteBecker Thanks. I thought compliance was implicit, like "Traffic law guarantees you can safely cross a green light *(unless someone runs a red, implicitly)*". You learn something new every day. :)

Answer (score 6):

`inline` is dangerous and expensive.

It is expensive because every compilation unit that uses something now depends on the definition of the thing.  So change the body?  Recompile every user of it.

It is dangerous because if two `inline` definitions disagree, your program is IF-NDR (ill formed, no diagnostic required).

Without `inline`, two definitions cause an ill formed program, but the compiler must provide a diagnostic; usually a hard error.

`inline` turns off that extremely useful warning.

If every compiler was capable of converting the IF-NDR of different `inline` definitions into a diagnostic error message you'd have more of a case.  So long as that proves difficult and/or not implemented, `inline` is a "activate unsafe mode!" option.  Making it default would be counter productive.

Comment: To expound on Yakk's point that `inline` is expensive:  if the programmer opts-in to use an inline without profiling and assessing the performance gain, then the expense (in any moderate sized project or larger) far outweighs the unknown performance gain (if any).  And "Whole Program Optimization" (WPO) or "Link Time Optimization" (LTO) may make any such expensive gain moot, for those executables that can leverage WPO or LTO.  Avoid `inline` unless it has a measurable benefit, or if your project is so small compiling overhead is a non-issue, or if your time is free.

Comment: @Eljay or when it need to be defined in header.

Answer (score 1):

The trade-off is that you need the definition of an `inline` function everywhere it's used. If you want that, just put your whole program in a single .cpp file.

The ODR is what you need to have separate compilation, and that is still useful.

Answer (score 1):

From [cppreference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/definition):

> One and only one definition of every non-inline function or variable
>   that is odr-used (see below) is required to appear in the entire
>   program (including any standard and user-defined libraries). The
>   compiler is not required to diagnose this violation, but the behavior
>   of the program that violates it is undefined.

Declaring a function as `inline` does not "ignore" ODR, but it causes each appearance of the function to be its own entity that needs a definition in each translation unit where it is used. Small, but significant difference. ODR is still required to have seperate translation units.